# Parse.com Android: LocalDataStore doesn't work

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a parse query:

```
   ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Message");


        query.whereEqualTo("recipient",currentUser);
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
        query.setLimit(10);
        query.include("sender");

  query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

                if(e == null) {

                    Log.i("OBJECT LENGTH?", objects.size() + " ");



            }

        });
```

If I turn on:

```
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
```

in my ParseApplication.class before the Parse.initialize call, the above query works the first time it is called (objects.size() is > 0, as it should be and is in the data browser) but then e.g. if I restart the app, the same code executed, returns 0.

Why?

So to be clear:

- Uninstall app
- Install app
- Login
- Start app
- Query executes successfully
- Terminate app, e.g. with force stop
- Start app
- Query returns 0

Redo those steps, with just clearing app data and no uninstall, and it works again once.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem that you are describing. It was a bug in the SDK version 1.5 which got fixed with the latest version 1.5.1:

> **Parse Android Changelog**
>
> v1.5.1 — May 30, 2014
>
> Fixed various bugs with Local Datastore.